# Firebase "value" returning duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project with the firebase realtime database and jquery. I have to retrieve data from two different nodes and store them in datatable. The first query returns values and on the base of that values, I have to retrieve the values from another node. Now problem is that it returns values fine but returns duplicate values.

Here is my code:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userRef = database.ref("Users");
var orderRef = database.ref("Orders");
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        userType = childSnapshot.val().UserType;

        if (userType === 'r') {
           restId = childSnapshot.key;
           displayName = childSnapshot.val().DisplayName;
           location = childSnapshot.val().Location;

           orderRef.on("value", function(oSnapshot) {
               oSnapshot.forEach(function(oChildSnapshot) {
                   location2 = oChildSnapshot.val().pickupLocation;

                   if (location === location2) {

                      deliveryLocation = oChildSnapshot.val().deliveryLocation;
                      driver = oChildSnapshot.val().driver;
                      status = oChildSnapshot.val().status;
                      completionTime = oChildSnapshot.val().timeOfCompletion;
                      pickupTime = oChildSnapshot.val().timeOfPickup;
                      date = oChildSnapshot.val().date;

                      table.row.add([restId, displayName, deliveryLocation, driver, status, completionTime, pickupTime, date]).node().id = "restId";
                       table.draw(false);
                   }
              });
            });
          }
        });
   });
```

Here is the output:
[image: Output Image]

Comment: Are you sure you need on() instead of once()? What exactly do you expect the output to be, and what is the contents of your database?

Comment: I have tried both on() as well as once() and having the same problem. In the output it should show only the first three rows because I have only three records in database.